# Proftpd: Use public key only to connect

Tags: docker, ssh-keys, public-key, proftpd

My requirement is such that there must be a custom proftpd docker image which any user can use. The user will run the docker container using the image and on running will mount a mount path to the docker. The mount path will contain the public key that the user will use. The user will not give the private key. The user would have generated the public and private key like shown below:

```
$ ssh-keygen -N "" -f /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This should output id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files.

The content of the public key file, id_rsa.pub, will be added to a file in the mount path (/mnt/blah/key) and then mounted while starting the docker container. The entrypoint script of the docker image looks like below:

```
DIR=/home/proftpd
#PASSWD_KEY=/mnt/blah/passwd_key
PUB_KEY=/mnt/blah/key

PASSWORD=abcboom

echo $PASSWORD | /usr/bin/ftpasswd --passwd --file=/home/proftpd/ftpd.passwd --name=virtual --uid=1234 --gid=5678 --home=/home/proftpd/ --shell=/bin/bash --stdin

/usr/bin/ftpasswd --group --name=--group --name=virtual --file=/home/proftpd/ftpd.group --gid=5678 --member=1234

touch /home/proftpd/.ssh/authorized_keys

cat $PUB_KEY > /home/proftpd/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /home/proftpd/.ssh/authorized_keys

proftpd -n -4 -c /home/proftpd/proftpd.conf -d10
```

So basically the content of /mnt/blah/key is being written into authorized_keys file. But since the requirement is that the user will not be providing private ,id_rsa, file content, is there a way that I can start the proftpd server without this information? I know that the official documentation of proftpd says that the SFTPHostKey directive is required in the proftpd.conf file, I have seen that it takes the private key file for it. Is there a way to workaround this?

I have the below proftpd.conf file:

```
ServerName                      "ProFTPD Default Installation"
ServerType                      standalone
DefaultServer                   on
AuthUserFile                    /home/proftpd/ftpd.passwd
AuthGroupFile                   /home/proftpd/ftpd.group
AuthPAM                         off
PidFile                         /home/proftpd/proftpd.pid
ScoreboardFile                  /home/proftpd/proftpd.scoreboard
WtmpLog                         off

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                           2345

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask                           022

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections 
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd).
MaxInstances                    30

# Set the user and group under which the server will run.
User                            proftpd
Group                           proftpd




# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
<Directory />
   AllowOverwrite                on
</Directory>

# A basic anonymous configuration, no upload directories.  If you do not
# want anonymous users, simply delete this entire <Anonymous> section.

TraceLog                        /home/proftpd/trace.log
Trace                           DEFAULT:10

LoadModule mod_sftp.c
#LoadModule mod_sftp_pam.c

<IfModule mod_sftp.c>
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
    SFTPEngine ON
    SFTPAuthMethods password publickey
    RequireValidShell off
    SFTPLog /home/proftpd/log/sftp.log
    Port 2360
    SFTPLog /home/proftpd/sftp.log
    SFTPCompression delayed
    SFTPHostKey /home/proftpd/.ssh/id_rsa ---> What to do here??
    SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys file:/home/proftpd/.ssh/authorized_keys
    SFTPOptions InsecureHostKeyPerms
    AuthUserFile /home/proftpd/ftpd.passwd
    AuthGroupFile /home/proftpd/ftpd.group
    AuthOrder mod_auth_file.c
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you are confusing two things... There is a user key pair with a public key on the server, and the private key in the user's custody. Then the server itself has an identification key pair with public and private keys and users that want to make sure they are talking to the server (no man-in-the-middle) can store the server's public key on their system (doing so is usually the default behavior on first connection). The SFTPHostKey would be the private key of that key pair.